# Conversion from MIFARE 14 byte UID to unknown 5 byte number

Tags: number-formatting, rfid

I have this Mifare 14 byte UID: "04502E22D45380" than i need to have converted to a 5 byte hex: "63AE03D0AA".
I have tried all kinds of conversions on the web and suggestions and haven't been able to convert it:

Tried to take each nibble from unkown type and Reverse the bits of each nibble (least significant bit becomes most significant bit, second bit becomes second last bit).
Didn't give a useful result.
Tried to take 0450 (0x4 50) away and tried the same, and many hex to binary, to hex... with the the Unique Serial Number:
[image]
But I'm running out of ideas. The supplier of the RFID scanner of the unknown number couldn't help either. They said:

> Thats difficult i'm afraid. It might have been a 4byte vs 7byte ID thing, but when i assume that we use the 4 and customer the 7byte ID and i XOR this. I don't get the expected result.

So I thought perhaps some of you could help.

Comment: i am not very use to MIFARE so could you please explain how and in what language are you going to write the code ?

Comment: Could be in Javascript, Python.
I'm more after the steps needed to get to the result.

Comment: there are many liberty for converting to hexadecimal or other but i am not sure if you are interesting in those as you said you are more interesting in step because the liberty will add another layer of abstraction on top of it .?

Comment: Sure! anything that can get the desired result is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

this is my try please check the print result if ok ?

```
import binascii

mifareUidpassed = "04502E22D45380" #<-- pass other uid if you want
unHexifi=binascii.unhexlify(mifareUidpassed)[:5]
convUid = binascii.hexlify(unHexifi).decode()

print("check this HexFied result here-->"+convUid)
```

here i used `binascii` library you can read more on it's documentation here [binascii.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html)

**not the part of answer but to discuss on result :**

after trying to find a potential mistack i try to run all the possible combination to extract hexadecimail out of the 14 digit UID

```
import binascii

mifareUidpassed = "04502E22D45380"

for i in range(16):
    for j in range(16):
        unHexifi = binascii.unhexlify(mifareUidpassed)[i:j]
        convUid = binascii.hexlify(unHexifi).decode()
        print("result here --> ", convUid, 'with the use of i:', i, 'and j:', j)
```

below i add the all print result please taake a look at it :

```
result here -->   with the use of i: 0 and j: 0
result here -->  04 with the use of i: 0 and j: 1
result here -->  0450 with the use of i: 0 and j: 2
result here -->  04502e with the use of i: 0 and j: 3
result here -->  04502e22 with the use of i: 0 and j: 4
result here -->  04502e22d4 with the use of i: 0 and j: 5
result here -->  04502e22d453 with the use of i: 0 and j: 6
result here -->  04502e22d45380 with the use of i: 0 and j: 7
result here -->  04502e22d45380 with the use of i: 0 and j: 8
result here -->  04502e22d45380 with the use of i: 0 and j: 9
result here -->  04502e22d45380 with the use of i: 0 and j: 10
result here -->  04502e22d45380 with the use of i: 0 and j: 11
result here -->  04502e22d45380 with the use of i: 0 and j: 12
result here -->  04502e22d45380 with the use of i: 0 and j: 13
result here -->  04502e22d45380 with the use of i: 0 and j: 14
result here -->  04502e22d45380 with the use of i: 0 and j: 15
result here -->   with the use of i: 1 and j: 0
result here -->   with the use of i: 1 and j: 1
result here -->  50 with the use of i: 1 and j: 2
result here -->  502e with the use of i: 1 and j: 3
result here -->  502e22 with the use of i: 1 and j: 4
result here -->  502e22d4 with the use of i: 1 and j: 5
result here -->  502e22d453 with the use of i: 1 and j: 6
result here -->  502e22d45380 with the use of i: 1 and j: 7
result here -->  502e22d45380 with the use of i: 1 and j: 8
result here -->  502e22d45380 with the use of i: 1 and j: 9
result here -->  502e22d45380 with the use of i: 1 and j: 10
result here -->  502e22d45380 with the use of i: 1 and j: 11
result here -->  502e22d45380 with the use of i: 1 and j: 12
result here -->  502e22d45380 with the use of i: 1 and j: 13
result here -->  502e22d45380 with the use of i: 1 and j: 14
result here -->  502e22d45380 with the use of i: 1 and j: 15
result here -->   with the use of i: 2 and j: 0
result here -->   with the use of i: 2 and j: 1
result here -->   with the use of i: 2 and j: 2
result here -->  2e with the use of i: 2 and j: 3
result here -->  2e22 with the use of i: 2 and j: 4
result here -->  2e22d4 with the use of i: 2 and j: 5
result here -->  2e22d453 with the use of i: 2 and j: 6
result here -->  2e22d45380 with the use of i: 2 and j: 7
result here -->  2e22d45380 with the use of i: 2 and j: 8
result here -->  2e22d45380 with the use of i: 2 and j: 9
result here -->  2e22d45380 with the use of i: 2 and j: 10
result here -->  2e22d45380 with the use of i: 2 and j: 11
result here -->  2e22d45380 with the use of i: 2 and j: 12
result here -->  2e22d45380 with the use of i: 2 and j: 13
result here -->  2e22d45380 with the use of i: 2 and j: 14
result here -->  2e22d45380 with the use of i: 2 and j: 15
result here -->   with the use of i: 3 and j: 0
result here -->   with the use of i: 3 and j: 1
result here -->   with the use of i: 3 and j: 2
result here -->   with the use of i: 3 and j: 3
result here -->  22 with the use of i: 3 and j: 4
result here -->  22d4 with the use of i: 3 and j: 5
result here -->  22d453 with the use of i: 3 and j: 6
result here -->  22d45380 with the use of i: 3 and j: 7
result here -->  22d45380 with the use of i: 3 and j: 8
result here -->  22d45380 with the use of i: 3 and j: 9
result here -->  22d45380 with the use of i: 3 and j: 10
result here -->  22d45380 with the use of i: 3 and j: 11
result here -->  22d45380 with the use of i: 3 and j: 12
result here -->  22d45380 with the use of i: 3 and j: 13
result here -->  22d45380 with the use of i: 3 and j: 14
result here -->  22d45380 with the use of i: 3 and j: 15
result here -->   with the use of i: 4 and j: 0
result here -->   with the use of i: 4 and j: 1
result here -->   with the use of i: 4 and j: 2
result here -->   with the use of i: 4 and j: 3
result here -->   with the use of i: 4 and j: 4
result here -->  d4 with the use of i: 4 and j: 5
result here -->  d453 with the use of i: 4 and j: 6
result here -->  d45380 with the use of i: 4 and j: 7
result here -->  d45380 with the use of i: 4 and j: 8
result here -->  d45380 with the use of i: 4 and j: 9
result here -->  d45380 with the use of i: 4 and j: 10
result here -->  d45380 with the use of i: 4 and j: 11
result here -->  d45380 with the use of i: 4 and j: 12
result here -->  d45380 with the use of i: 4 and j: 13
result here -->  d45380 with the use of i: 4 and j: 14
result here -->  d45380 with the use of i: 4 and j: 15
result here -->   with the use of i: 5 and j: 0
result here -->   with the use of i: 5 and j: 1
result here -->   with the use of i: 5 and j: 2
result here -->   with the use of i: 5 and j: 3
result here -->   with the use of i: 5 and j: 4
result here -->   with the use of i: 5 and j: 5
result here -->  53 with the use of i: 5 and j: 6
result here -->  5380 with the use of i: 5 and j: 7
result here -->  5380 with the use of i: 5 and j: 8
result here -->  5380 with the use of i: 5 and j: 9
result here -->  5380 with the use of i: 5 and j: 10
result here -->  5380 with the use of i: 5 and j: 11
result here -->  5380 with the use of i: 5 and j: 12
result here -->  5380 with the use of i: 5 and j: 13
result here -->  5380 with the use of i: 5 and j: 14
result here -->  5380 with the use of i: 5 and j: 15
result here -->   with the use of i: 6 and j: 0
result here -->   with the use of i: 6 and j: 1
result here -->   with the use of i: 6 and j: 2
result here -->   with the use of i: 6 and j: 3
result here -->   with the use of i: 6 and j: 4
result here -->   with the use of i: 6 and j: 5
result here -->   with the use of i: 6 and j: 6
result here -->  80 with the use of i: 6 and j: 7
result here -->  80 with the use of i: 6 and j: 8
result here -->  80 with the use of i: 6 and j: 9
result here -->  80 with the use of i: 6 and j: 10
result here -->  80 with the use of i: 6 and j: 11
result here -->  80 with the use of i: 6 and j: 12
result here -->  80 with the use of i: 6 and j: 13
result here -->  80 with the use of i: 6 and j: 14
result here -->  80 with the use of i: 6 and j: 15
result here -->   with the use of i: 7 and j: 0
result here -->   with the use of i: 7 and j: 1
result here -->   with the use of i: 7 and j: 2
result here -->   with the use of i: 7 and j: 3
result here -->   with the use of i: 7 and j: 4
result here -->   with the use of i: 7 and j: 5
result here -->   with the use of i: 7 and j: 6
result here -->   with the use of i: 7 and j: 7
result here -->   with the use of i: 7 and j: 8
result here -->   with the use of i: 7 and j: 9
result here -->   with the use of i: 7 and j: 10
result here -->   with the use of i: 7 and j: 11
result here -->   with the use of i: 7 and j: 12
result here -->   with the use of i: 7 and j: 13
result here -->   with the use of i: 7 and j: 14
result here -->   with the use of i: 7 and j: 15
result here -->   with the use of i: 8 and j: 0
result here -->   with the use of i: 8 and j: 1
result here -->   with the use of i: 8 and j: 2
result here -->   with the use of i: 8 and j: 3
result here -->   with the use of i: 8 and j: 4
result here -->   with the use of i: 8 and j: 5
result here -->   with the use of i: 8 and j: 6
result here -->   with the use of i: 8 and j: 7
result here -->   with the use of i: 8 and j: 8
result here -->   with the use of i: 8 and j: 9
result here -->   with the use of i: 8 and j: 10
result here -->   with the use of i: 8 and j: 11
result here -->   with the use of i: 8 and j: 12
result here -->   with the use of i: 8 and j: 13
result here -->   with the use of i: 8 and j: 14
result here -->   with the use of i: 8 and j: 15
result here -->   with the use of i: 9 and j: 0
result here -->   with the use of i: 9 and j: 1
result here -->   with the use of i: 9 and j: 2
result here -->   with the use of i: 9 and j: 3
result here -->   with the use of i: 9 and j: 4
result here -->   with the use of i: 9 and j: 5
result here -->   with the use of i: 9 and j: 6
result here -->   with the use of i: 9 and j: 7
result here -->   with the use of i: 9 and j: 8
result here -->   with the use of i: 9 and j: 9
result here -->   with the use of i: 9 and j: 10
result here -->   with the use of i: 9 and j: 11
result here -->   with the use of i: 9 and j: 12
result here -->   with the use of i: 9 and j: 13
result here -->   with the use of i: 9 and j: 14
result here -->   with the use of i: 9 and j: 15
result here -->   with the use of i: 10 and j: 0
result here -->   with the use of i: 10 and j: 1
result here -->   with the use of i: 10 and j: 2
result here -->   with the use of i: 10 and j: 3
result here -->   with the use of i: 10 and j: 4
result here -->   with the use of i: 10 and j: 5
result here -->   with the use of i: 10 and j: 6
result here -->   with the use of i: 10 and j: 7
result here -->   with the use of i: 10 and j: 8
result here -->   with the use of i: 10 and j: 9
result here -->   with the use of i: 10 and j: 10
result here -->   with the use of i: 10 and j: 11
result here -->   with the use of i: 10 and j: 12
result here -->   with the use of i: 10 and j: 13
result here -->   with the use of i: 10 and j: 14
result here -->   with the use of i: 10 and j: 15
result here -->   with the use of i: 11 and j: 0
result here -->   with the use of i: 11 and j: 1
result here -->   with the use of i: 11 and j: 2
result here -->   with the use of i: 11 and j: 3
result here -->   with the use of i: 11 and j: 4
result here -->   with the use of i: 11 and j: 5
result here -->   with the use of i: 11 and j: 6
result here -->   with the use of i: 11 and j: 7
result here -->   with the use of i: 11 and j: 8
result here -->   with the use of i: 11 and j: 9
result here -->   with the use of i: 11 and j: 10
result here -->   with the use of i: 11 and j: 11
result here -->   with the use of i: 11 and j: 12
result here -->   with the use of i: 11 and j: 13
result here -->   with the use of i: 11 and j: 14
result here -->   with the use of i: 11 and j: 15
result here -->   with the use of i: 12 and j: 0
result here -->   with the use of i: 12 and j: 1
result here -->   with the use of i: 12 and j: 2
result here -->   with the use of i: 12 and j: 3
result here -->   with the use of i: 12 and j: 4
result here -->   with the use of i: 12 and j: 5
result here -->   with the use of i: 12 and j: 6
result here -->   with the use of i: 12 and j: 7
result here -->   with the use of i: 12 and j: 8
result here -->   with the use of i: 12 and j: 9
result here -->   with the use of i: 12 and j: 10
result here -->   with the use of i: 12 and j: 11
result here -->   with the use of i: 12 and j: 12
result here -->   with the use of i: 12 and j: 13
result here -->   with the use of i: 12 and j: 14
result here -->   with the use of i: 12 and j: 15
result here -->   with the use of i: 13 and j: 0
result here -->   with the use of i: 13 and j: 1
result here -->   with the use of i: 13 and j: 2
result here -->   with the use of i: 13 and j: 3
result here -->   with the use of i: 13 and j: 4
result here -->   with the use of i: 13 and j: 5
result here -->   with the use of i: 13 and j: 6
result here -->   with the use of i: 13 and j: 7
result here -->   with the use of i: 13 and j: 8
result here -->   with the use of i: 13 and j: 9
result here -->   with the use of i: 13 and j: 10
result here -->   with the use of i: 13 and j: 11
result here -->   with the use of i: 13 and j: 12
result here -->   with the use of i: 13 and j: 13
result here -->   with the use of i: 13 and j: 14
result here -->   with the use of i: 13 and j: 15
result here -->   with the use of i: 14 and j: 0
result here -->   with the use of i: 14 and j: 1
result here -->   with the use of i: 14 and j: 2
result here -->   with the use of i: 14 and j: 3
result here -->   with the use of i: 14 and j: 4
result here -->   with the use of i: 14 and j: 5
result here -->   with the use of i: 14 and j: 6
result here -->   with the use of i: 14 and j: 7
result here -->   with the use of i: 14 and j: 8
result here -->   with the use of i: 14 and j: 9
result here -->   with the use of i: 14 and j: 10
result here -->   with the use of i: 14 and j: 11
result here -->   with the use of i: 14 and j: 12
result here -->   with the use of i: 14 and j: 13
result here -->   with the use of i: 14 and j: 14
result here -->   with the use of i: 14 and j: 15
result here -->   with the use of i: 15 and j: 0
result here -->   with the use of i: 15 and j: 1
result here -->   with the use of i: 15 and j: 2
result here -->   with the use of i: 15 and j: 3
result here -->   with the use of i: 15 and j: 4
result here -->   with the use of i: 15 and j: 5
result here -->   with the use of i: 15 and j: 6
result here -->   with the use of i: 15 and j: 7
result here -->   with the use of i: 15 and j: 8
result here -->   with the use of i: 15 and j: 9
result here -->   with the use of i: 15 and j: 10
result here -->   with the use of i: 15 and j: 11
result here -->   with the use of i: 15 and j: 12
result here -->   with the use of i: 15 and j: 13
result here -->   with the use of i: 15 and j: 14
result here -->   with the use of i: 15 and j: 15
```

Comment: Unfortunately not.
The result of the print gives: "04502e22d4" where i need "63AE03D0AA".
But i'll check what more the library can, as well.

Comment: please take a look at discussion part print result and say if you gets any thing in you mind to add